# Sparql - query to get all triples related to a specific subject

Tags: sparql

I want all the triples in the graph from a specific subject / node.

I can get all the triples...

```
SELECT $s $p $o WHERE { $s $p $o }
```

... not really helpful

I can get all the directly connect triples...

```
SELECT $s $p $o WHERE { 
   $s _some_predicate_ _some_object_specifier .
   $s $p $o }
```

What I want is to start at `$s (selected by predicate and object)` and then get
something like `$s $p* $o`

Thoughts?

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCoDu.png)

So I'd like to start at ID_6 and get all node below that including the nodes 1 and 2. I also need the predicates because not all the predicates will be HAS

So more specifically using the graph below I want all the triples below object "**P2**" I need the subject, predicate and object for each of the 1xx and 2xx nodes... I can recursively query each node to get the data but I'm hoping there is a simple (ish) query to get all the data in a single query...

[More Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVimO.png)

Comment: "Something like `$s $p* $o`" is not very clear in terms of what you want, precisely. Can you give a concrete example: some example RDF graph, and what you'd like to be able to query from that RDF graph? As-is, the question is rather too broad and vague to answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this, but whether it is "simple" is somewhat subjective.

*Property paths* allow you to query paths of unknown length. However, you can only specify such arbitrary-length property paths on specific property names (so not on property *variables*).

A way around this is to use a negation, like so:

```
:P3 (:overrides|!:overrides)+ ?child
```

This will gives you back all "children" connected via paths of length 1 or longer where the connecting property is either `:overrides` or NOT `:overrides` (which is, of course, true for every property).

However, using property paths, you can only *match* these properties to get their *values* back, you can't get actually get the property names *themselves* back. So we will need to make our query a bit more extensive and just query for everything connected to both our original subject (`:P3`) as well as to all possible "child" subjects (`?child`).

The full query then becomes:

```
CONSTRUCT {
   :P3 ?prop ?val .
   ?child ?childProp ?childPropVal . 
   ?someSubj ?incomingChildProp ?child .
}
WHERE {
     :P3 ?prop ?val ;
         (:overrides|!:overrides)+ ?child . 
     ?child ?childProp ?childPropVal.
     ?someSubj ?incomingChildProp ?child. 
}
```

The reason this works is that we match and return both incoming and outgoing properties for *every* child along the way: so for a child connected to `:P3` via a path of length 2, we get the first component of the path back because `:P3 ?prop ?val` matches it, and the last part because `?someSubj ?incomingChildProp ?child` matches it. For a path of length 3, the middle part of the path will be matched because it was already retrieved by `?child ?childProp ?childPropVal` when the path was still at length 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [property path](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-property-paths/)

```
SELECT ?s ?p ?o
WHERE 
{
   ?s HAS+ ?o .
   FILTER ( ?s = <ID_6> )
}
```